# Help decrypting in ColdFusion passwords created in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, coldfusion, encryption

I have a SQL db storing passwords that were encrypted through a .NET application, that I need to decrypt through a ColdFusion app.  I just can't seem to get things set upproperly for the CF decryption to work.  Any help would by appreciated.  Thanks.

The .NET decryption code is:

```
public string Decrypt(string input) 
 { 
  try 
  { 
   DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider(); 

   int ZeroBasedByteCount = (input.Length / 2); 

   //Put the input string into the byte array 
   byte[] inputByteArray = new byte[ZeroBasedByteCount]; 

   int i; 
   int x; 

   for (x = 0;x<ZeroBasedByteCount;x++) 
   { 
    i = (Convert.ToInt32(input.Substring(x * 2, 2), 16)); 
    inputByteArray[x] = (byte)i; 
   } 

   //Create the crypto objects 
   des.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key); 
   des.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key); 
   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); 
   CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write); 

   //Flush the data through the crypto stream into the memory stream 
   cs.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length); 
   cs.FlushFinalBlock(); 

   //Get the decrypted data back from the memory stream 
   StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder(); 

   foreach(byte b in ms.ToArray()) 
   { 
    ret.Append((char)b); 
   } 

   return ret.ToString(); 

  } 
  catch(Exception ex) 
  { 
   throw(ex); 
   return null; 
  } 
 }
```

Comment: Where is the key variable coming from?

Comment: Whilst it doesn't solve this specific problem, you shouldn't need to be decrypting passwords anyway - they should always use a one-way hash, and to check attempts you encrypt those and compare the two encrypted values.

Comment: @Peter Boughton: Amen to that.

Comment: No argument from me, but this is the task at hand.  The users and their passwords are being moved from one system to another and must go in the clear.  They will by encrypted by the new system as they are added

Comment: Huh - are you really using the same value as key and initialization vector?

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the [docs for the CF `Decrypt` function](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c1c.html) and determined what values you need for the encoding, IVorSalt, and/or iterations arguments? (It looks like the algorithm is `DES`.)

Comment: I've read the docs and it looks like what I'mm having trouble with is processing the password and the key, which i have from the old system, so that they provide the same values in CF as they doin .NEt.  The CF process will need to give the same value as--

Comment: int ZeroBasedByteCount = (input.Length / 2);    //Put the input string into the byte array    byte[] inputByteArray = new byte[ZeroBasedByteCount];    int i;    int x;    for (x = 0;x<ZeroBasedByteCount;x++)    {     i = (Convert.ToInt32(input.Substring(x * 2, 2), 16));     inputByteArray[x] = (byte)i;    }    //Create the crypto objects    des.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);    des.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);